# how can one draw big symbol of `{}`

Tags: symbols

How can I draw a big `{}` as below shape:

[image]

I tried by `\big{` but it does not solve.

Comment: `\bigl\{`   `\bigr\}`

Comment: It should be `\bigl\{` (with `\{` not `{`). Larger versions come with `\Big`, `\bigg`, and `\Bigg`.